# Installing Win8, fails due to missing or error in file adpu32.sys

Tags: windows-8

I just bought a new HDD, Seagate Barracuda® 7200.12 1TB. I removed my previous master HDD, and replaced this with the new one. I turned on the pc, with the win8 cd inside my CD-ROM and booted up from my cd drive. This HDD doesn't have any OS, for obvious reasons. When I tried to install Win8, I just got the error message telling me something like this:

```
Your pc needs to be repaired.
Operation System cannot be loaded because of a critical system driver is missing or contains error. 
Windows\System32\drivewrs\adpu32.sys
```

The progress got 70% finished before the regularer "*We need to boot to apply the new settings bla..bla*" The above error message occured at this time.

I googled for hours, to figure out this.

Came over [this forum thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/windows-8-is-stuck-in-an-automatic-repair-loop/2310c795-d39b-460f-9e4c-c95008e5ce51) at microsoft's own support forum. I tried what the user *JustinKostic* wrote:

```
bootrec /fixMBR
bootrec /Fixboot
bootrec /rebuildBCD
and also
chkdsk /r c:
chkdsk /r d:
chkdsk /r e:
chkdsk /r f:
```

And then tired to do a automatically repair of the computer, which is under advanced settings. This menu wants me to select a specific Operation System, and the only one is Win8, so obviosly something has been installed. But when I try to do the automatically repair, the only error message I get is:

```
Automatic repair couldn't repair your pc
Press "Advanced options" to try other options to repair your pc or "Shut down" to turn off your pc
```

I did try the reset your pc, but this also fails!

What is going on here? So frustrating, I've strugged with this for nearly 20 hours now.. Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the system have an Adaptec SCSI Card by any chance?

Comment: @Karan I dont think so.

Comment: Hmm, all I can think of is: 1) Try a GParted LiveCD/USB (or GParted from a Linux LiveCD/USB) to partition and format the drive first. 2) Try the Win8 DVD. 3) If that fails, try Win8 setup from a USB. 4) If that fails, check your HDD using SeaTools.

Comment: @Karan I tried to install ubuntu, version 9.02 or something.. I just had a Live CD in my drawer. I will try to install win7, and then upgrade to win8 from here. If this won't work, I will send back the HDD to store I bought it from. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, so you tried to install Ubuntu, and what happened? Did that fail as well? Did you try to simply partition+format the drive using GParted, instead of installing Linux?

Comment: @Karan The installation of ubuntu also failed, I could clearly see that there was alot of scratches on the CD. But I installed Win7 succecfully. From here I tried to install win8, but with same error. So I will try to install win8 directly from the .iso file, I suspect that there is some errors with my burner.. And to answer your last question: I formatted my HDD several times.